# Dynamically loading json content within a HTML Script

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am writing a webpage using HTML and javascript. I have written a script (as seen below) that loads records from a json file. My script is meant to load data from the json file and display like a bootstrap alert. When I first ran it, the script worked, but strangely subsequent tests did not work. Does anyone have any ideas to fix this?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Script in Question -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // This is a way to load data from a JSON file and load it into places in the html document. Based on: https://howtocreateapps.com/fetch-and-display-json-html-javascript/
            fetch('alerts.json')
                .then(function(response){
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(function (data){
                    appendData(data);
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            function appendData(data) {
                var container = document.getElementById("alerts");
                for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var div = document.createElement("div");
                    div.className = "alert alert-primary";
                    div.setAttribute("role", "alert")
                    div.innerHTML = data[i].content;
                    container.appendChild(div)
                }
            }
        </script>
        <title>Guitars</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="alerts" style="text-align: center;">
        <!-- JSON data appears here -->
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: center;" id="main">
        <!-- Other stuff here -->
        </div>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
        <!-- Other stuff here -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

alerts.json:

```
[
    {"content":"Welcome back, test1!"}, 
    {"content":"Welcome back, test2!"},
    {"content":"Welcome back, test3!"}
]
```

The code reads the records from alerts.json and inserts them into a div with an id "alerts" - as seen in the `<script>` tag. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What "did not work" about it?

Comment: `fs = require('fs')` `fs` is nodeJS code so 1) you shouldn't be using it for client code, and 2) you're not using it anyway so you can remove that line.

Comment: @David when i ran my webpage from nodejs, i would not see the bootstrap-style alert on the page, that function is meant to produce.

Comment: @Andy thank you for that, i will remove the line.

Comment: @JeremyRoy: In your browser's debugging tools, are there any errors on the development console?  When you use your browser's script debugger, what specifically happens when stepping through the function that you call?  Do the runtime values of the variables match what you expect?  Does a specific operation fail?  Now is a good time to do some debugging and provide details about the problem.

Comment: @David there were some errors pertaining to other undefined scripts/variables unrelated to this problem specifically. But clearing them up, my function worked!! Cheers for prompting me to check that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here. Thanks to user @David,  it was suggested to clear out all errors found in the webpage debugging console. Upon clearing these up, the function then worked as intended!